# pdf form sends FDF instead of PDF

Tags: php, pdf, acrobat

**UPDATE**
 i discovered it sends PDF if opened by adobe reader at my computer, but same pdf form sends FDF if opened in Chrome browser at website
**UPDATE END**

i am using Acrobat XI Pro trial version

Adobe Acrobat offer forms in pdf documents, those forms can be submitted to server

submit button settings
http://gyazo.com/0ff0dc17210f39f062a131c85265406c

my server code

```
<?php

ob_start();
$file = file_get_contents("php://input"); //Gets binary PDF Data
$time = microtime(true);
$newfile = "./customers/" . $time . ".pdf"; //Names file based on the time to the microsecond so nothing gets overwritten.
$worked = file_put_contents($newfile, $file); //Creates File
ob_end_clean();

?>
```

and i am getting FDF data instead, not PDF document

Comment: What is the exact filename u getting and its mime type ?

Comment: FDF is one of the format pdf forms can export(includes form name and values only). 

data i am getting:

<pre>%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj
<</FDF<</F<</Type/Filespec/F....
</pre>

Comment: Darshan Jain

i am getting data stream.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: @mkl i give me a hint! i discovered it sends PDF if opened by adobe reader at my computer, but same pdf form sends FDF if opened in Chrome browser from webserver

Comment: Chrome's PDF viewer is of limited quality only. I'm actually surprised it supports PDF form posting at all.

Comment: How big is the FDF, how big is the PDF?

Comment: *ANSWER FOR MY QUESTION* - please use an answer for answering, do not edit the answer into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general Adobe PDF Forms full functionality available only in Adobe Reader. Google Chrome pdf viewer sends only FDF format. Firefox pdf viewer don't allow form editing/sending at all. Maybe obvious, but i am php developer and never worked with PDF Forms.